# Understanding reference bandwidth

Tags: java

I'm reading a book about java 8 by Richard Warburton. In the section about Primitive stream author gives some explanation about primitives vs references (emphasized mine):

> For algorithms that perform lots of numerical operations, the cost of
>   boxing an unboxing combined with the ***additional memory bandwidth used***
>   ***by allocated boxed objects*** can make the code significantly slower.

What is the bandwidth? Is it considered as for primitives we have the actual value of them in memory and can work with them directly.

For references, in turn, we work with pointers to the heap and to invoke a method on some object we have to perform indirection by a given pointer and only then we can invoke the method. Is that considered a bandwidth?

Do we really have to worry about the bandwidth in practice?

Comment: IMHO, this means that boxed objects need significant more memory than primitive types do. Also, in java there are no pointers. Primitive types are always stored on the stack and objects are always stored on the heap. The instances of boxed objects your work in an application are always referencing the original object on the heap. So i think with bandwidth the author just means that the memory the application has to work on gets larger by using many boxed objects that contain primitives instead of directly using primitives.

Answer (score 3):

A realistic computer has a limitation on how quickly it can retrieve bytes/words from memory, with one faster speed for reading from CPU caches, and a slower speed for reading from memory that is not in the L1/L2/L3/... cache.

When we're working through a large primitive/boxed stream, we can assume that we don't have elements of the collection in the CPU cache, and they need to be fetched from main memory.

In a gross oversimplification applicable to OpenJDK, an object in memory will contain references to its `java.lang.Class` and all superclasses thereof (used for checking casts and related), followed by its fields. This can be fairly sizable, for example with the boxed `java.lang.Integer` where it would likely need to maintain a reference to `Class<Integer>` and `Class<Number>`. Needless to say, this is much larger than the 32 bits needed for a primitive.

When one is iterating/streaming a collection of `Integer`s, it's necessary to load these objects into memory, and for simple numerical operations on the elements, the memory becomes the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes. When dealing with boxed objects instead of primitives, you have reference overhead as well as object overhead. However that's not something that you should really be constantly thinking about.

Of course you want to be careful that you're using for example `int[]` instead of `Integer[]` if you don't need an object array, but there are usually far better places for optimization before you need to worry about primitive vs. boxed. In DB or network bound systems the CPU caches usually have very little saying in the final throughput of the application. In a CPU bound system this is naturally more relevant as explained in *hexafraction's* answer.